# Plumber in container on Azure how to map ports

Tags: r, azure, api, containers, plumber

I build container with `plumber` API inside. It runs on port 80 in container and I also exposed port 80. I also mapped ports

```
az container create ... --ports 80:80
```

Since Azure only support symmetrical port mapping.

But I still cannot reach my API from container FQDN and I do not know how to troubleshoot. I already confirmed that API is running fine within the container with `curl` command.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

did you run your plumber server with host 0.0.0.0?

Take a look at plumber official Docker image

https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I can give it a shot. Although, I do not understand why the IP matters.  I know for sure that API is already running in the container. I just need ports to be mapped properly.

Comment: The IP matter, if you see the application on host 127.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1, the application cannot be accessed externally. You should change the host parameter to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: External request won't be routed to localhost IP, this is done at OS level and has nothing to do with plumber.

Comment: I tried your set up with locally installed Docker, and you are right it worked with `host = "0.0.0.0"` and did not work with `"127.0.0.1"`. I am still very much confused how this IP routing happens and Google search on your statement "External request won't be routed to localhost IP" did not clarify much.

Comment: I tried to run API on `host = 0.0.0.0` on Azure and it failed, while it worked perfectly fine on Docker running locally.

Comment: Is your url behind https? In this case, you will have to put your plumber API behind an nginx server because plumber does not support https. See https://github.com/meztez/plumberDeploy/blob/master/inst/server/nginx-ssl.conf. You will have to provide your own certificate.